# TopDown Island Generation

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, terrain

I am trying to generate an island using Simplex Noise. To actually make a island shape i used Amitp's answers to the following questions:

1.[Fast, simple procedural 2d island generation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80548/fast-simple-procedural-2d-island-generation)

2.[Generating random Pools or lakes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/generating-random-pools-or-lakes)

Using them i have snippet of code for generation:(width/height is 128)

```
for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            // amitp's solution
            Vector2 vec = new Vector2(2 * x / WIDTH - 1, 2 * y / HEIGHT - 2);
            float d = Mathf.Sqrt(vec.x * vec.x + vec.y * vec.y);
            //
            float noise = Noise.Generate((float)x / WIDTH * 10, (float)y / HEIGHT * 10);

            // amitp's solution again
            mapData[x, y] = noise > 0.3 + 0.4*d*d ? noise * 10 : 0.0f;
            //

            colors[x + y * WIDTH] = new Color(mapData[x, y], mapData[x, y], mapData[x, y]);
        }
    }
```

This gives me the following unwanted result:

[image: Wrong]

How do i get fix it to generate properly?

Lastly i'm using Unity.

***EDIT:

Fixed/Changed a couple of things and now i am getting this(still not what i want):

[image: changes/fixes]

with this changed code:

```
for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            // amitp's solution
            Vector2 vec = new Vector2(((2 * x) / WIDTH) - 1, ((2 * y) / HEIGHT) - 1);
            float d = Mathf.Sqrt((vec.x * vec.x) + (vec.y * vec.y));
            //
            float noise = Noise.Generate((float)x / WIDTH, (float)y / HEIGHT);

            // amitp's solution again
            mapData[x, y] = noise > 0.3 + 0.4*d*d ? noise * 10 : 0.0f;
            //

            colors[x + y * WIDTH] = new Color(mapData[x, y], mapData[x, y], mapData[x, y]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "(still not what I want)" - can you describe what it is that you *do* want? What would you like to change about the results you have now? I presume centering & scaling the island relative to the whole square, not just the top-right quadrant, and getting rid of the cropped edges. Anything else?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I want it to be centered, which i don't know why it is not doing that. As well as what you said, removed cropping and scale nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest this aproach.
Let fs(x,y) be your simplex noise function.
Let's introduce a second function : `f(x,y) = ((float)Math.Sin(((float)x/(float)WIDTH) * Math.PI) ) * ((float)Math.Sin(((float)y / (float)WIDTH) * Math.PI) )` or any function that rassemble the following and that gives values from 0 to 1:

[image]

at this point take your simplex noise fs(x,y) :

[image]

and multiply per f(x,y) you get something like this :

[image]

finaly apply a colorgradient to obtain something like :

[image]

Comment: I am actually struggling to find a simplex noise implementation that returns values in the 0 to 1 range. Can any one lead me to one?

Comment: I saw you use unity : try Mathf.PerlinNoise http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html

Comment: I'm not very keen on Unity's Perlin Noise method. When i use it, it just seems to give repetition of 'rolling hills'. Maybe i am using it wrong, but.

Comment: Ok, found a way to use a perlin noise function that gives good results but returns in the range of -1 to 1. I then found a post that give a small formulae to change the -1 to 1 range into 0 to 255 range. Now just the matter of getting the mask formulae to work.

Comment: Ok, so the formlae : f(x,y) = WIDTH * (1 - (X * X + Y * Y)) : isnt giving me numbers in the range of 0 to 1, its giving me the range of 0 to large negative numbers.

Comment: The function was wrong , I edited the response and  redefined as   f(x,y) = ((float)Math.Sin(((float)x/(float)WIDTH) * Math.PI) ) * ((float)Math.Sin(((float)y / (float)WIDTH) * Math.PI) )

Comment: Thanks, that works but the mask is bigger than the one you gave above. I will show the sort of outputs im getting at the moment in pic.

Comment: These are the types of output i'm getting: http://imgur.com/CRQ11jH . The noise is top-left, mask is bottom-left and final result is middle right. The mask is alot whiter than the one above?

Comment: given : X = ((float)Math.Sin(((float)x/(float)WIDTH) * Math.PI) ) and Y =  ((float)Math.Sin(((float)y / (float)WIDTH) * Math.PI) ) try X * X * Y * Y instead of X * Y

Comment: Ok, after some messing around with some code i got it to work nicely: http://imgur.com/GqRXpHn . Just need to apply some color. Got any suggestions on way to apply color rather than just putting the noise values into an if-else statment?

Comment: in your final result , you have a 0..1 float for each point. The esiest way is to set up an array of colors and interpolate a color using the pixel float 0..1 value. See : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98740/how-to-color-lerp-between-multiple-colors/98750#98750 or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993394/Csharp-color-gradient-control

Comment: Thanks, i believe i can use the Gradient class as mentioned in one of those posts. I will mark this as answered now. :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just finished implementing basic color-gradient and thought i would show the result: http://imgur.com/uHtaaWM