# How can I apply Perlin noise to generating an asteroid from cubic voxels?

Tags: procedural-generation, perlin-noise

I know I can use Perlin noise to generate randomised terrains, but for my current project i want to generate random *asteroids* of non-uniform length, width depth etc.

My first thought was to apply Perlin noise to a sphere, but i do not know how i would apply this with cubes space in a grid nor did i know whether it would make the asteroids appear *random* enough, my current assumption was they would all be relatively spherical still.

Is Perlin noise still the best method to be using for terrain not on a single plane?

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer.  It is explained in 2D but the same concepts can be taken into 3D and will work the same way:  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120471/creating-a-set-of-islands-by-subtracting-gradient-values-from-a-perlin-noise

Comment: @Jon but i don't understand _how_ to take the concepts to 3D.

Comment: You just add the third dimension.  You will also need a way to generate a spherical gradient, which perlin noise does not do.

Comment: @Jon I am still failing to see how i can do that, the spherical gradient i get & is a helper in the right direction, but the main point of my question is i do not understand how to apply this in 3d space.

Comment: Added code for 3D blend.  This should do what you want, however, you will still have to figure out how to generate a 3d Spherical gradient pattern to blend with your perlin noise data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can blend data of noise and gradient together, in 3D.  This should provide you with asteroid style shapes.

First, our container to store the Data:

```
public class MapData {

    public float[,,] Data;
    public float Min { get; set; }
    public float Max { get; set; }

    public MapData(int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        Data = new float[width, height, depth];
        Min = float.MaxValue;
        Max = float.MinValue;
    }
}
```

We init this data container as follows:

```
blendData = new MapData (Width, Height, Depth);
```

Now, if you already have your generated noise, and gradient maps, you can blend them as follows:

```
// first pass - blend gradient values
for (var x = 0; x < Width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < Height; y++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < Depth; z++) {

        // Get gradient values
        float gradValue1 = (float)NoiseMap.Get (nx, ny, nz);
        float gradValue2 = (float)GradientMap.Get (nx, ny, nz);

        // Multiply
        float blendValue = gradValue1 * gradValue2;

        // keep track of the max and min values found
        if (blendValue > blendData.Max) blendData.Max = blendValue;
        if (blendValue < blendData.Min) blendData.Min = blendValue;             

        blendData.Data[x,y,z] = blendValue;               
    }
}
```

Doing so will give you some pretty crazy values, so we are going to want to normalize these in order to provide an easier way to work with this data in the future:

```
// secondary pass to normalize the blended values
for (var x = 0; x < Width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < Height; y++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < Depth; z++) {
            blendData.Data[x,y,z] = (blendData.Data[x,y,z] - blendData.Min) / (blendData.Max - blendData.Min);
        }
    }
}
```

Render this data, and you should see a asteroid style shape emerge.

Comment: No i am still not getting it I am afraid. I am using the `Mathf.PerlinNoise` function available in Unity and am unsure how i can get a 3D `NoiseMap` entity from that data.

Comment: You need to generate that NoiseMap with your PerlinNoise.  So you would have another step before all this, where you would fill an Array[x,y,z] with your perlin noise data.  This would be your Noise Map.

Comment: So i generate 3 perlin noise maps (one for each axis) and somehow blend them together?

Comment: No.  You generate 1 perlin noise map, fetching the noise data in 3 dimensions.  Unfortunately I just realized that Unity only provides a lame 2D perlin noise generator.  You are going to have to get an external lib to do this in 3D

Comment: Ok, that is the step i was finding hard to get over. I will attempt this.

Comment: You might be interested in a tutorial series I wrote.  It shows you how to utilize Accidental Noise library in Unity.  Take a look here:  http://www.jgallant.com/procedurally-generating-wrapping-world-maps-in-unity-csharp-part-1/

Comment: Link to lib here:  https://github.com/TinkerWorX/AccidentalNoiseLibrary

Comment: i have tried this, and before the normalization pass the data looks almost workable, but after the normalization it is as if i am back to just random noise? what is the normalization intended to do? EDIT: actually this could be to do with the spherical gradient function i created... all i did was was create an entity with heigh/width/depth variables, and it basically calculates the distance from the center of a sphere and returns a figure where 0 would be outside the sphere and 1 would be at the center point of the sphere, is this incorrect? i cant find examples of making a spherical gradient?

Comment: (forgot to add, between 0-1 was a float depending on distance from the center to the edge of the sphere the given point was at)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40987/discussion-between-jon-and-james-trotter).